# The maximum air drag force doesn't coincide with the maximum velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, drag

I'm trying to decode my data from an experiment conducted today. We wanted to calculate the air drag acting on a pendulum. In order do to this, we first created a model for our frictional force F:

[image]

Using some mechanics, we derived that $$ml^2\ddot{\theta} = F l - mgl\sin(\theta)$$

Which yielded us an equation for the force $$F = ml\ddot{\theta} + mg\sin(\theta)$$

The angular acceleration and the angle of displacement could be retrieved from our experiment using a set of cameras. This data was then feed into the equation derived above, mysterically however, when the force is plotted against time, alongside the velocity of the blob, we find that they're not in phase. What is expected is that the force exerted by air drag should be maximum at the bottom, where the velocity is as it maximum, instead, the force is 0.

We used a pendulum of length 36 cm, and a mass of 67 grams. Here's what the plot looks like:

[image: LUE GRAPH]

As you can see, the force is at a maximum for when the blob is stationary.

We know that the force is proportional to the velocity using some facts about Reynolds number and so forth..., (or the derivative of our angle with respect to time), so that would yield us a sine wave (supposing the angle is represented by a cosine wave). The force is then a sine wave, but according to our equation, the RHS must be a sum of two cosine waves, since the second derivative or angle with respect to time gives us a cosine again, so the equations doesn't seem to hold. What can possibly creates this fault?

Comment: Not even the frequency of your computed resistance force is correct. What you have here is either a programming bug or a systematic error in your data acquisition or both. I wouldn't be surprised if you are looking at a trivial sampling error due to insufficient frame rate (causing beating) and a first order velocity measurement formula. Working with sampled data requires a basic mathematical knowledge of the sampling theorem and how one reduce errors with higher order formulas/filters. Given the kind of high school experiment that you are doing here that's a little advanced, I am afraid.

Comment: @FlatterMann The frame rate was put at 500 hz for our cameras, so I don't think it's lacking there. Maybe as you said it's a programming bug. Thanks either way!

Comment: I can clearly see a beating frequency in your data. That is usually a sampling error due to a low sampling rate. Try the experiment with a slower pendulum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position data clearly shows a beating frequency, which is not possible with a single mass pendulum. This is therefor most likely a sampling artifact. Since according to the comments the framerate of the camera is already fairly high, I would suggest to repeat the experiment with a slower pendulum. Increasing the pendulum length by a factor of four should lead to a decrease in the frequency by a factor of two, which should lead to far more accurate position sensing.

Having said this, it just occurred to me that there is another possible source for the beating: it's the structure that the pendulum is attached to. If it is not rigid enough, then it will couple to the motion of the pendulum and the coupled system can produce an actual physical deviation from simple (almost) harmonic motion that would look similar to the observed motion. I would therefor probably check the rigidity of the attachment point first before modifying the geometry.